# Gravity Forms - Dynamically populate drop down with user entered information

Tags: drop-down-menu, parameter-passing, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to set up a drop down in Gravity Forms based on information the user entered . For example, I have three "Single Line Text Fields", once the user gets to another part of the form, I want the user to select one of the choices they entered on these three "Single Line Text Fields".  To give you a better visual, say they entered Lemon for Text field 1, Orange for Text field 2 and Apple for Text field 3, how do I make it appear on a Drop Down later on in the form they are filling (same page)? I know that I have to enter a Parameter for each of the Single Line Text Fields, but what code do I use for this? I am bit confused about some of the code they provided. If anyone could let me know or point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Gravity Forms Populate Anything's [live merge tags](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/#live-merge-tags) can handle this. Here's what it would look like:

[image]

Happy to answer any questions!